# pandas finding duplicate rows with different label

Tags: pandas

I have the case where I want to sanity check labeled data. I have hundreds of features and want to find points which have the same features but different label. These found cluster of disagreeing labels should then be numbered and put into a new dataframe.
This isn't hard but I am wondering what the most elegant solution for this is.
Here an example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "feature_1" : [0,0,0,4,4,2],
    "feature_2" : [0,5,5,1,1,3],
    "label" : ["A","A","B","B","D","A"]
})

result_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "cluster_index" : [0,0,1,1],
    "feature_1" : [0,0,4,4],
    "feature_2" : [5,5,1,1],
    "label" : ["A","B","B","D"]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the output you want (both de-duplication and cluster_index), you can use a `groupby` approach:

```
g = df.groupby(['feature_1', 'feature_2'])['label']

(df.assign(cluster_index=g.ngroup()) # get group name
   .loc[g.transform('size').gt(1)]   # filter the non-duplicates
   # line below only to have a nice cluster_index range (0,1…)
   .assign(cluster_index= lambda d: d['cluster_index'].factorize()[0])
)
```

output:

```
   feature_1  feature_2 label  cluster_index
1          0          5     A              0
2          0          5     B              0
3          4          1     B              1
4          4          1     D              1
```

Answer (score 1):

First get all duplicated values per `feature` columns and then if necessary remove duplciated by all columns (here in sample data not necessary), last add [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) for groups indices:

```
df = df[df.duplicated(['feature_1','feature_2'],keep=False)].drop_duplicates()

df['cluster_index'] = df.groupby(['feature_1', 'feature_2'])['label'].ngroup()
print (df)
   feature_1  feature_2 label  cluster_index
1          0          5     A              0
2          0          5     B              0
3          4          1     B              1
4          4          1     D              1
```